# iOS 6 Appearance API UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd not working?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In iOS 6, you have access to a new method in the Appearance API:

```
- (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)backgroundImage
              forState:(UIControlState)state
                 style:(UIBarButtonItemStyle)style
            barMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)barMetrics
```

So you can set different background for each navigation button style. Thing is, it looks like it is not working for the `UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd` style, but it works for let say, `UIBarButtonItemStyleDone`. Here's an snippet of my code:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 6.0f)
{
    // Works well
    [barButton setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav-button-done.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:7 topCapHeight:0]
                         forState:UIControlStateNormal
                            style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                       barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    // Not working
    [barButton setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav-button-done.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:7 topCapHeight:0]
                         forState:UIControlStateNormal
                            style:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                       barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

Anybody has a clue why it is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the method declaration for UIBarButtonItem:

```
- (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)backgroundImage forState:(UIControlState)state style:(UIBarButtonItemStyle)style barMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)barMetrics
```

Problem is that UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd is not a valid UIBarButtonItemStyle. The supported styles are:

```
typedef enum {
    UIBarButtonItemStylePlain,
    UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered,
    UIBarButtonItemStyleDone,
} UIBarButtonItemStyle;
```

Your conflating UIBarButtonItemStyle with UIBarButtonSystemItem, they are not really the same and it is just ignoring the value your setting on it and reverting to default type.

Comment: Oh gotcha, so there's no easy way to target only the Add button (the one with the plus sign) easily with UIApparence?

Comment: No that is a SystemItem Button, the point of those is that you get the uniform system appearance. You can create one that looks like it but it will have to be a custom button of some kind. Not that hard, just more work :)